# Getting inappropriate records while joining 2 tables and skipping records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This are 2 properties of my table:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestOperation> TestOperation { get; set; }
}


public class TestOperation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TestId { get; set; }
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to fetch list of only those tests skipping last 2 test from the `Test` table which have entry in `TestOperation` table  but I will have more than 1 records for each test.

**Test Table :**

```
TestId   Version
339        1
340        2
341        3
342        4
343        5
344        6
345        7
346        8
347        9
348        10
349        11
350        12
351        13
352        14
```

**Test Operation table output for below query:**

```
select TestId, count(*) from [dbo].[TestOperation] group by TestId

TestId    Count(*)
340        10
341        21
342        41
343        8
344        30
345        21
346        18
347        5
348        20
349        31
350        34
351        20
352        16
```

**Expected Output skipping last 2 records from above output:**

```
TestId  Version
340       2
341       3
342       4
343       5
344       6
345       7
346       8
347       9
348       10
349       11
350       12
```

Note that in the `Test Operation` table I don't have any records for Test Id 339.

**Query:**

```
var output = (from m in context.Test
              join c in context.TestOperation on m.Id equals c.TestId
              orderby m.Id descending
              select new
              {
                  testId = m.Id,
                  version = m.Version
              }).Skip(2).Distinct().ToList();
```

This above query is giving me `Test 351` and it's wrong because I don't want the last 2 records from my Test table and in my query I am skipping 2 records from the list. So why am I seeing test ID 351?

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting both your code and your text. Next, it's not at all clear why you'd expect not to see any records for test 351... if you have two records for test 352 for example, your `Skip(2)` will be skipping both of those joined results.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have duplicate values but if your real data set does, then you should probably be doing `Distinct` before `Skip` and not after. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @JonSkeet : Thank you for editing the question and reason for test 351 is that as i said that i dont have record for test 339 in TestOperation table so i want to consider record from 340 to 352 and then i would like to skip last 2 records from 340 to 352 that is why i dont want record 351

Comment: @stephen.vakil I havent posted Test operation table records but as i said in my question that i will have more than 1 records for each test and i have tried Distinct before skip but was getting error that is why i have changed the order of distinct and skip

Comment: What error do you get from `Distinct`?  As mentioned, `Skip(2)` on 350, 350, 351, 351, 352, 352 will lop off the duplicate `352` values and your list will start at `351`

Comment: Sorry, that's still *really* unclear. You're ordering by ID descending, and skipping the first two values... so if there are two entries corresponding to ID 352, then you could skip those and still end up with a record for 351. It would really be helpful if you'd give us complete sample data with expected and actual results. (If I were you, I'd try the same thing in LINQ to Objects too... that would mean you could post a [mcve].)

Comment: @JonSkeet :I have updated my question with all inputs and expected output

Comment: But your join will include *all* the test ID 352 pairs - 16 of them - so I'd expect two of *those* to be skipped, and none of the test ID 351 pairs. Perhaps you want to put the `Skip` after the `Distinct`, as stephen.vakil suggested... You said that gave you an error, but not what the error was.

Comment: @JonSkeet :I encountered this error :The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: Right, so move the ordering to after the `Distinct()` as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet i need to add ordering after Distinct() like this :Distinct().OrderByDescending(t => t.testId).Skip(2).ToList() ??

Comment: That certainly seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet :Yeah it worked out in the way you have suggested me.so you rock like as usual.thank you so much :)